# Google domain in address bar different

Tags: google-chrome, search

I live in Canada and use Google.ca exclusively. It's been set as my default search engine for years. For the past couple days, when I enter a search in the Chrome address field, search results return from the United Arab Emirates, like this:

[image]

The weird part is if I enter the search in the Google home page search field, the search return under Google.ca.

I checked my Region Settings under Google Home > Settings > Region Settings. They were set to Current Region (I'm in Canada, never been anywhere near the UAE) but I changed the setting to Canada to see if that helped. (The bottom of my Google Home settings were showing Unite Arab Emerates, but now they show Canada after I made the change:

[image]

This seemed to fix the search domain for the Google Home page but now the Chrome address field. (Weird they would be different?)

I also checked my language settings in my Google settings and they're English.

I have an ExpressVPN account and it puts my IP in the U.S. (I verified). Also, they issue is on all my devices.

I did set up a couple new Google Homes (Insignia brand) a day before the problem started. I can't imagine its related, but the weird part is they don't seem to recognize my voice as well since this issue started?

Also, I check to see if any weird Chrome extensions were added during a recent install and there were none. I also ran MalwareBytes which found a bunch PUP setting issues

[image]

Which I quaranteed, but no improvements.

I'm out of ideas. Thoughts greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried a fresh Chrome user profile?  Google attempts to use Geolocation.  So make sure that this happens when you are NOT connected to your VPN, and it does happen, with other browsers.  If it happens only while connected to a VPN and with all browsers, then this is a problem with Google’s Geolocation or your Google account (which then would justify moving this question)

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. I disconnected the VPN and that fixed the problem. I've had the VPN for a couple months and the issue only started a couple days ago. Do you think it's still related to Google's Geolocation?

Comment: I think it’s due to the VPN true server location, either that, Google has old information with regards to the address itself.

Comment: I reconnected the VPN and the problem returned. Investigating, my D-Link 810L firmware was out of date (1.01). I updated to 1 03 and it fixed the problem.